# CURL Post - Length required

Tags: php, cookies, curl, http-status-code-411

I've made a simple code to login to my website.

```
private function request($url, $reset_cookies, $post_data)
  {

    $options = array(
      CURLOPT_URL               => $url,
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER    => 1,
      CURLOPT_HEADER            => 0,
      CURLOPT_FAILONERROR       => 1,
      CURLOPT_USERAGENT         => $this->user_agent,
      CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT    => 30,
      CURLOPT_TIMEOUT           => 30,
      CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER    => 0,   
      CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION    => 1,
      CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS         => 10,
      CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER       => 1,
      CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION     => $reset_cookies ? 1 : 0,
      CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR         => $this->session_id,
      CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE        => $this->session_id,
    );

    // Add POST data
    if (isset($post_data))
    {
      $options[CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST] = 'POST';
      $options[CURLOPT_POST]          = 1;
      $options[CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS]    = http_build_query($post_data);
    }

    // Attach options
    curl_setopt_array($this->curl, $options);

    // Execute the request and read the response
    $content = curl_exec($this->curl);

    // Handle any error
    if (curl_errno($this->curl)) throw new Exception(curl_error($this->curl));

    return $content;
  }
```

So basically, a normal step for my login system would be:

1. Send a GET request to retrieve the security token and initialize a cookie session. (DONE and WORKING)

   ```
   $security_token = $this->browser->request('https://mysite.com/login', true, null);
   ```
2. Send a POST request with the username, the password and the security token.

   ```
   $postdata = array(
       'login' => $login,
       'password' => $password,
       '__RequestVerificationToken' => $security_token,
   );
   $login_page = $this->browser->request('https://mysite.com/login', false, $postdata);
   ```

On step #2, I got a 411 error saying the content length is required.

Did I make something wrong or did I forget to set a parameter ?

Comment: Have you looked at: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=curl+required+length+is%3Aquestion

Comment: @Mike Yes I've already read those pages. I haven't found any solution

Comment: I forgot to say that I'm using the same instance of Curl for my two requests.*

Comment: Have you looked into http://php.net/curl_multi_exec ?

Comment: Even if I do a single POST request I got the same issue. So I don't think multi_exec would solve this.

Comment: Solved. I just removed that line `$options[CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST] = 'POST';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution was to remove this line

```
$options[CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST] = 'POST';
```